# bbpress edit and reply pages are showing blank pages

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, bbpress

I have a custom wordpress theme and i have installed bbpress in it. In my theme i have created a file called `single-topic.php`. In which i am displaying topic and corresponding replays. I want to add admin capabilities to each reply. I have added following code

```
<div class="bbp-admin-links">
<?php do_action( 'bbp_theme_before_reply_admin_links' );  ?>
<?php echo bbp_get_reply_admin_links(['id'=>$reply_id ]);
do_action( 'bbp_theme_after_reply_admin_links' ); ?>
</div>
```

in which `$reply_id` is reply id which am getting correctly.
After adding this all admin capabilities come under each reply, like edit,trash,spam ,etc
But the problem is that `edit` link is not working , it is just returning a blank page.

For eg. url will come linke this. `http://localhost:8888/wp/forums/topic/xzzxx/edit/`

What is the problem here. why it is returning to blank page. Can you please help me. Edit will work same as stackoverflow post edit an, inline editor will come

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but BuddyPress hides the body using CSS ( `display: none !important;` ), so just check the display property of the body, and change it to ( `display: block !important;` )